# MySQL - Select all events starting from a given date PLUS the most recent event BEFORE the given date

Tags: mysql

For example, if I have

```
Event
------
id
start_date
end_date
...
```

I can use:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE start_date > NOW()
```

But I want to also include the one most recent event with start_date BEFORE now.. so I revised it to this:

```
(SELECT * FROM event WHERE start_date < NOW() ORDER BY start_date DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL  
(SELECT * FROM event WHERE start_date > NOW())
```

Which gives me the desired result, but I'm wondering if there is a more straightforward way to accomplish this, perhaps without using an extra UNION and SELECT, because my actual query is more complicated with joins and I would prefer not to repeat it. Is there a better way to write that query?

Comment: I think you have it exactly how you need to. You really are asking for two totally different things: an array of what happened after x, and a single item that happened right before x, I can't think of a way you could phrase that in an `OR` filter or really any way that wouldn't mean running two queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE start_date >= (
  SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM event WHERE start_date < NOW()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! Sounds promising to me.. I'm just on the way out and will probably have to wait until Monday to fully test it but I will flag as the answer if it works.